# Switching between Horizontal Menu and Drop Down Menu

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, contextmenu, media-queries

I have an unordered inline horizontal list menu, when my mobile media query kicks in I want the css to change so that it has a parent item called 'menu' that when clicked displays the menu child links in a vertical list.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Should I create both types of menu and use css to switch their visibility or is there a way I can make the first menu become the new second menu?

Any help would be really appreciated. I am sure switching between hidden css property on each would work but I wasn't sure how semantic friendly this would be etc?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Righto, it took a bit of work but I've created a working example of what you're after [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9bgrQ/9/)

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="nav-status">Open / Close</a>
<ul id="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 5</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
</ul>
```

​**CSS**

```
/* FOR ANYTHING GREATER THAN MOBILE RESOLUTION */
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    #nav-status {
        display: none;    
    }

    ul {
        width: 100%;    
        min-height: 25px;
        color:#fff;
        background:#CCC;
        overflow: visible;
    }

    ul li {
        color:#000;
        border-right: 1px solid #333;
        width: 96px;
        height: 21px;
        padding:2px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        position: relative;    
    }

    ul li:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }

    ul li ul {
        display: none;
        width: 100px;
        color:#fff;
        background:#666;
        position: absolute; 
        top: 25px; 
        left: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    ul li:hover ul {
        display: block;    
    }
}

/* FOR MOBILE RESOLUTIONS */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #nav-status {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 21px;
        padding: 2px;
        background: #000;
        color: #FFF;   
    }

    ul {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;       
        color:#fff;
        background:#CCC;
        overflow: visible;
    }

    ul li {
        color:#000;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 21px;
        padding:2px;
        display: block;        
        position: relative;    
    }

    ul li:last-child {
        border-bottom: none;
    }

    ul li ul {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        color:#fff;
        background:#666;        
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }        
}
​
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function() {
    $('#nav-status').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#navigation').toggle();
    });​
});
```

In summary, any time the resolution drops under 480px wide, the mobile styling will kick in. This'll basically stack the menu items vertically and allow you to collapse/expand the nav with the open/close link. Anything larger than 480px will use the default styling which will order the menu items horizontally.

Hopefully it all makes sense :-)

Comment: That's brilliant and just what I am after, thank you.  I don't want to be a pain but now we have that (which is great anyway), can we try make 1 addition? If the main menu on screen is too long when displayed on iPad portrait (I think landscape width will be okay) can we turn some of the li's (say item 2,3 and 4) to become sub links under a 'new' dropdown item? I guess similar to what you have done but with mobile button? So mobile is as you have it, screen above say 800px is shown full length, but iPad portrait (below 800px) shows 75% of the lis and 25% under a new dropdown located mid menu?

Comment: In the example you originally sent Alimac83, if you resize the browser window small so it switches to mobile view, use the open/close button, then resize the browser window the menu has disappeared? Do you know why this happens and if there is a fix for it? Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue. If I decrease the size of output window and toggle the menu and back to increasing the size of the output window, the output window is a blank white screen as seen here : https://imgur.com/a/Zr6qcYD.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the html markup the same, but set your media queries to intercept your chosen resolution and style the elements differently.

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/rYVz4/

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
</ul>​
```

CSS

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  ul { display: block; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; }
  ul li { display: inline-block; padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px; width: 100px; float: left; } 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul { display: block; width: 110px; overflow: hidden; }
  ul li { display: inline-block; padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px; width: 100px; } 
}
```

As you can see, whenever the resolution is greater than 600px wide, the elements will be styled to float left and take up 100% of the width of the screen.

On any smaller resolution, the elements will stack vertically.

You can read more about media queries [here](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-media-queries)

If you need more advanced behaviour, you can tie this in with javascript. This is one way of doing it:

```
function checkResolution() {
  // Resolution width > 600px
  if ($(window).innerWidth() > 600) {
    // implement styling for these devices                                          
  }
}

$(function () {
  $(window).resize(function () {
    checkResolution();
  });

  checkResolution();
});
```

This code will tie into the window.resize event which'll run the relevant code if your browser is resized.

​

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply alimac83, I'll check this out and give it a try. Thanks for the advice re Javascript as well, that might be useful.

Comment: If I set the parent 'menu' ul to display:none (hidden) for the inline horizontal menu then it removes all the links that are it's children and therefore hides the whole menu. Is there a way to only hide the parent link but not it's children, unless of course it's the mobile version where the opposite should happen (parent shown and children hidden).

Comment: It doesn't logically make sense to do so. If you're wanting to display an entirely different nav for mobile then you may as well build two separate lists and choose to show/hide depending on the resolution. I wouldn't make it complicated for yourself by trying to show/hide individual elements within the ul. PS. Do you happen to have any code we can look at? It'll help me get a better understanding of the problem..

Comment: Okay thanks, part of the reason for asking the question is because I don't want to over complicate things unnecessarily. For example, if I can keep as pure css and no js then great, the simpler the better and I was thinking the same for the way the menu css works, simpler the better. I would like the mobile menu's child items to be hidden though and for an additional 'menu' link to appear only on mob version. I do not have any code for you but it will be a list of 11 items (12 on mobile where the extra 'menu' appears). The 10th link drops down to an additional two items (say 10A and 10B).

Comment: This is the menu structure: http://jsfiddle.net/9bgrQ/2/. I want it to be easy to update as well, for adding extra submenu child dropdowns in the future if needed. The jsFiddle shows how it would look in expanded state on the mobile.

Comment: I've made a few more tweaks, ul dropdown needed to go in li I think. http://jsfiddle.net/9bgrQ/3/

Comment: I can see your example but what exactly are you wanting to happen?

Comment: Sorry for delay, to avoid confusion I have renamed 'menu' link as 'open/close' and have a new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9bgrQ/4/ I'd like the menu in my example to, in most cases, be horizontal with item ten expanding to reveal 10A & 10B on hover and with NO 'Open/Close' button/link showing (this is for most screens other than mobile). For mobile (e.g. say below 480px width) to only show the 'open/close' button/link, when 'open/close' clicked or hovered the menu expands vertically for mobile format.

Answer (score 0):

If the menu has the same items in both cases, I cannot see any reasons to make two copies of it. I would just make two different css-files, one for "regular" browsers and one for mobile media. 
In the "regular" one, the "menu" parent item is hidden, and the menu is horizontal. In the mobile media one, the menu parent item is visible, the menu is a hidden vertical list that shows up (through css or javascript) when the menu parent item is clicked.

Comment: Great, thanks for your reply. This sounds like what I am after. I'll try and create both using the same list then, sounds sensible. Thanks